# DateTimePicker control install error

Tags: asp.net

I have a question about a third-party DateTimePicker control.
I've downloaded the dll and paste the appropriate web.config lines.
I've put the control into the aspx page. When I load the page an alertbox appears:

> No «add verb="GET" path="/JavascriptDateTimeFormat.axd" /» httpHandler.

The control's textbox and the buttons are present but does nothing.

Part of my web.config is:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="mark" assembly="Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker" namespace="Mark.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="GET" path="/helpdeskweb/JavascriptDateTimeFormat.axd" type="Mark.Web.UI.JavascriptDateTimeFormat, Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this entry into web.config between HttpHandlers tag

add verb="GET" path="**JavascriptDateTimeFormat.axd**" type="Mark.Web.UI.JavascriptDateTimeFormat, Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker"

make sure the path is as mention in bold.

Answer (score 3):

Just omit the name="JavascriptDateTimeFormat" and everything should work. The added line in IIS7 is:

```
<add verb="GET" path="JavascriptDateTimeFormat.axd"
  type="Mark.Web.UI.JavascriptDateTimeFormat, Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker"/>
```

Alexander

Answer (score 1):

If this is for IIS7, you need to change it slightly.  In this case, you need to put the following line in the  section of the  subsection:

```
<add name="JavascriptDateTimeFormat" verb="GET" path="JavascriptDateTimeFormat.axd" type="Mark.Web.UI.JavascriptDateTimeFormat, Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker"/>
```

It's nearly the same, but the syntax and location is slightly different.

Comment: Yes this is IIS7. After I changed the section you wrote, the Visual Studio 2008 tells on name -> "The 'name' attribute is not declared." The alert still comes and the control does not work. Have you any additional idea about it?
Thanx

Comment: You need to add it to the `<handlers>` section.

Answer (score 1):

He didn't specify, but you need to put it in the

```
<handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete solution to this problem.
It's best to have sections for IIS6 AND IIS 7:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="JavascriptDateTimeFormat" verb="GET" path="JavascriptDateTimeFormat.axd" type="Mark.Web.UI.JavascriptDateTimeFormat, Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="/JavascriptDateTimeFormat.axd" type="Mark.Web.UI.JavascriptDateTimeFormat, Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```